# How to Ascertain Sine Wave and Harmonics

Tags: data, parameter-estimation

I have some data that I've noticed conforms to a sine wave. Details of the data is unknown. My task is to approximate it as closely as possible.

From some experimentation in Excel, I noticed the data follows a sine wave, so attempted to plot in the base sine wave (orange) and am now trying to approximate the blue line. I believe this is a simple job of harmonics being added to the base sine wave, however; the quantity and their respective amplitude and harmonic number (2nd harmonic being 2 * f, 3rd harmonic being 3 * f etc) is what I now need to calculate. I'm also guessing the amplitude of the resulting wave is modified by possibly a sine wave too.

Is there software which could automate this and approximate it through some analysis (Fourier analysis maybe) or possibly brute force, or is it something I have to write myself?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) to get an idea of the distribution of the frequency components. Check out the 'psd' package in r or the [signal processing toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html) if you have access to Matlab.

Comment: Interesting, I don't have access to Matlab, but is it possible to do it in octave?

Comment: I have not used it, but there does seem to be a signaling package: http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/

Comment: Thanks! As I've achieved a mini-victory spotting this sine wave after modifying the input data, I'll reward myself and go to bed now! I'll experiment with Octave in the morning!

Comment: Am I right in assuming that peaks in the positve mean the signal has that particular frequency and negative troughs mean the frequency is present, but out of phase? How exactly do I determine the precise phases of the sines?